# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{\sin(9(n+1))}{\sin(9n)}\right\rvert$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sin(9n+9)=\sin(9n)\cos(9)+\cos(9n)\sin(9).$$

So

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{\sin(9(n+1))}{\sin(9n)}\right\rvert=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\cos(9)+\frac{1}{\tan(9n)}\sin(9)\right\rvert.$$

I guess the sequence diverges but I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: use laws of limit to transform this into $c_1+c_2 \cdot |\lim_{n \to \infty} \cot 9n|$ which does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Take two sequences $n_k' = \dfrac{\pi k}{9}$ and $n_k''$ such that $\tan(n_k'') = \dfrac{\sin(9(n''_k+1)}{\sin(9n''_k)}$, for example.

---

[image]

Comment: I am still not sure. Shouldn't we take subsequences of natural numbers?

Comment: @JunpyoChoi Assume $n$ is a continuous variable since the limits will be the same.